# How to control or prevent rendering of HTML page till it download all resource file?

Tags: html, uiviewcontroller, html-rendering

How to control rendering of HTML page till it download its all HTML, CSS and JS dependencies?

Adding to the above question, how to validate that all the dependencies have been downloaded successfully ?

FRAMEWORK I AM USING:- jQuery, Twitter Bootstarp

Browser compatibility required:- IE8+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work. Basically, you hide the body by default. When everything loads, you show it:

**HTML**:

```
<body class="placeholder">
  ...
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
.placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).load(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('placeholder');
});
```

Just as a question: why would you need to do this?

Comment: Honestly speaking, this is nothing to do with any functionality, its just because my client to add a UI feature.

Comment: How does page loading affect the UI?

Comment: Its just an feature Client wants to get it added, just to simulate it with a feature in GMAIL

Comment: Ah, so more of a loading screen? That makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, 1 more question, Like we add load function on DOCUMENT Level, Ca n we add similar feature on DIV level.Basicaaly I want to load a DIV only upon successful download of all its dependencies.